# Done Bar Button isn't dismissing view controller

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8, uibarbuttonitem

Can anybody please tell me why my 'Done' bar button isn't dimissing my view i'm trying to edit the data from the table view?Here is the link of my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gylo67z2n00yc9i/TableView.zip?dl=0
I want to know the reason.I can't figure out what i have missed out.

Answer (score 0):

1.add following method in checkListViewController.

```
 -(IBAction)unwindTocheckListViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

}
```

2. select Storyboard and select Add Item View Controller Scene.
3. Press ctrl on your Mac, select Done button and drag(pressing ctrl) to Exit.
4. A pop up opens up with above method name. Select it.
5. Repeat same for Cancel button.
   You done!!!

Read upon UnwindToSegue. where your codes goes etc.
Hope this helps.

```
        -(IBAction)unwindTocheckListViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue 
        { 
        SourceViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController]; 
        /*
       values of properties declared in .h file of your source ViewController
       (called rightly SourceViewController) can be passed to 
       viewController you coming back to(Unwinding to).

       */
        }
```

here source is your View controller where Done button is, this helps to bring your input from source to destination view controller.

Comment: I have done everything you mentioned.By Done button dimiss my view controller.But don't update the texts to my table view.I want to know what part of code should i implement into the method?

Comment: I couldn't understand your answer.Anyway, can you please edit my code and send me to my email: info.riduan@gmail.com ?